# bootstrap ui modal templateUrl not working

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've got a .cshtml view with a section for the modaldialog content.

```
<div data-ng-controller="paymentsOverviewAppCtrl"
     ng-mvc-pseudoform
     ng-form
     name
     class
     ng-class>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="paymentsOverviewByInstallation.modalContent">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Test
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>
 etc....
```

My ts file:

```
 var app = angular.module("app");

interface IPaymentsOverviewScope extends IBaseViewModel {
    model: Models.PaymentsOverview.PaymentsOverviewModel;
    setSort: ($event: Event, field: string) => void;
    isDescending: (sortField: string) => string;
    statusText: (status: boolean) => string;
    loadMorePayments: ($event: Event) => void;
    formattedDate: (jsonDate: string) => Date;
    canLoadMore: boolean;
    loading: boolean;
        openDetail: () => void;
}

class PaymentsOverviewController extends BaseController {

    constructor(
        public $scope: IPaymentsOverviewScope,
        public $location: ng.ILocationService,
        public $element: ng.IRootElementService,
        public $timeout: ng.ITimeoutService,
        public $window: ng.IWindowService,
        public $http: ng.IHttpService,
        public $modal,
        public dataEndpointService: DataEndpointService,
        _) {

        super($scope, $element, _);

        var modalInstanceCtrl = ($scope, $modalInstance) => {
            $scope.ok = () => {
                $modalInstance.close();
            };

            $scope.cancel = () => {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        };

        $scope.openDetail = () => {

            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                animation: true,
                //template: '<div class="modal-header"><h3 class="modal-title">Im a modal!</h3></div>',
                templateUrl: 'paymentsOverviewByInstallation.modalContent',
                controller: modalInstanceCtrl,
                size: 'lg',
            });

            console.log("templ: " + modalInstance.templateUrl);
        };
    }
}

app.controller("paymentsOverviewAppCtrl", PaymentsOverviewController);
```

When I use `templateUrl: 'paymentsOverviewByInstallation.modalContent'` the modal doesn't open. When I use `template: '<div class="modal-header"><h3 class="modal-title">Im a modal!</h3></div>'` the modal does open and shows the passed html. 
Why won't it work with templateUrl? I looked here for the example: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and then the Modal block

Error in my console: GET http ://mySite.site.local.be/nl/Orders/paymentsOverviewByInstallation.modalContent?noCache=1431524276826 404 (Not Found)
Using MVC and Sitecore

Comment: You need to save your plnkr and send that link out...the current link just goes to a new blank plnkr.

Comment: @BradBarber, editted my post to the original docs of the Modal. The plunker can be found there.

Comment: What Angular-UI script file are you using? I would make sure your using ui-bootstrap-tpls.js unless you built your own templates.

Comment: ui-bootstrap-tpls.js is present. Could it be something with MVC. I have an error in my console:GET http mySite.site.local.reference.be/nl/Orders/paymentsOverviewByInstallation.modalContent?noCache=1431524276826 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

It was something someone had overwritten in the code. That's why it didn't work.